# Afx Unsupported in Windows 10/ Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I retargeted an MFC solution from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015, but when I built it I received an error telling me the compiler could not find afxdisp.h normally found under VC->atlmfc->include . -- Of course I copied the file from the VS 2013 location, but I was wondering why it was missing? Does anyone know?

Comment: VS 2015 is RC. File a defect report, and don't just blindly copy files over.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a defect. Why is it bad to copy it over?

Comment: Because things change and the definitions in the older header files may no longer be valid or correct.

Comment: Better than not working at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, MFC is an addon in VS, and I did not have all of it (only had ATL). I relaunched installer went to custom install and clicked MFC classes. I also installed the Multibyte MFC library from the Visual Studio Website. It is not available in the custom options.